# What's the proper way to use Firebase Authentication along with Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Hi all—I'm building an app using Next.js and Firebase, both brand new technologies for me. It's a simple app where a user creates an account and must log in. If the user doesn't create an account, the app is useless—they can't move on to the next screen, which is a dashboard. Anyway, when they log in, they can then create a trip/vacation itinerary. I'm using Firebase Auth for auth and Firestore (not real-time db) as my db. My goal is that when a user logs in, the user can see every itinerary that they created and no one else's. It should be full CRUD. This is the first time I've done this sort of authentication as well, so that's likely adding to my confusion.

I know that my code isn't right, but it sort of worked. What keeps happening is that it seems like there's a lag when a user logs in and out. I've tested this on my local copy. When I log out and then log back in as a different user, it tells me that the uid is null. Anywhere from 1 - 30 minutes later (seriously), all of a sudden the page loads for the uid that I logged in with! Everything that I've read says that there's a lag with the authentication, but I couldn't really find a solution other than just pointing out the problem—so basically writing a console log that says who's logged in at the time and then the same when they've logged out. Also, I watched / read tons of tutorials, so maybe it's my code? I'm so sorry in advance for this novel of code—I'll organize as best as I can!

---

**Here's my config info, so I'm referring to Firebase as fire. The sign-in method is email and password, and everything looks as it should in Firebase as far as capturing that information on the Authentication screen.**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyB-xEPETXSfjboKe5H0kPUu-ZdRDGfszmA',
  authDomain: "where-to-jess.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: 'https://where-to-jess-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/',
  projectId: "where-to-jess",
  storageBucket: "where-to-jess.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "914509599583",
  appId: "1:914509599583:web:80cdf3e4090417b0f35cea"
};
try {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} catch(err){
  if (!/already exists/.test(err.message)) {
    console.error('Firebase initialization error', err.stack)}
}
const fire = firebase;
export default fire;
```

---

**When a user creates an account, they're also added to a collection 'users' in my db. I am using React Hooks (for the first time) as well. Their email is their username to login, but I'm capturing their email in the db. They are also immediately logged in upon account creation. This part also works.**

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setPassword('');

    fire.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userName, password)
    .then(() => {
      fire.firestore().collection('users').doc(fire.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .set({
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        email: userName
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('user wasn\'t added to db: ', error);
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('user wasn\'t able to create an account: ', error);
    })
    router.push('/users/dashboard')
  };
```

---

**This is my login code:**

```
const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    fire.auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('user wasn\'t able to login: ', error);
      })

    setUsername('')
    setPassword('')
    router.push('/users/dashboard')
  };
```

---

**Now for the fun part! This is my code for form submission for the itinerary. What I'm trying to achieve here is to have this newly created itinerary attached to their uid in the 'users' db. I'm leaving out all the form stuff because it's super long. This also seems to work—I can see it coming in in the db for whichever account I'm using.**

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    fire.firestore()
    .collection('users').doc(fire.auth().currentUser.uid).collection('itineraries')
    .add({

      //
    })

    .catch(error => {
      console.log('itinerary not added to db ', error)
    })
    router.push('/users/dashboard')
  }
```

---

**Here's where it all went to heck! I suspect it's because I'm cutting corners, which I'll explain next. This dashboard should show ONLY itineraries that the current logged-in user created. If the current logged-in user didn't create any itineraries, I'd get an error saying that the uid was null. SO, my workaround was to just create a fake itinerary manually in the db on their account (since I was testing) and give the tripName value as null. This seems to work, but this is where the weird login / logout stuff happens.**

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [itineraries, setItineraries] = useState([]);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  fire.auth()
  .onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      console.log(user.email + " is logged in!");
      setLoggedIn(true)
    } else {
      setLoggedIn(false)
      console.log('User is logged out!');
    }
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe =
    fire.firestore()
    .collection('users').doc(fire.auth().currentUser.uid).collection('itineraries').where('tripName', '!=', 'null')
    .onSnapshot(snap => {
      const itineraries = snap.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
      }));
      setItineraries(itineraries);
      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
      };
    });
  }, []);


  const handleLogout = () => {
    fire.auth()
      .signOut()
    router.push('/')
  };
```

---

**Lastly, here is the one rule that I have on the db. I got confused reading the rule docs, and I feel like I cut a corner here.**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read
      allow write
    }
  }
}
```

---

Again, I'm really sorry for ALL of that code. This is my first time using React Hooks, Next, and Firebase—so it's a mashup of Firebases's docs, tutorials, and my own code. I'd appreciate ANY help or advice here.

Answer (score 2):

That rule will allow all access to all documents in your db at present. You want something like this:

```
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /users/{user_id}{
           allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == user_id;
        }
    }
}
```

That will allow access only to users that are authenticated

Comment: thank you so much—such a basic thing! that's what i get for trying to learn next, firebase, and hooks at the same time... that combined with reordering my code above fixed the issue completely. i wasn't putting useEffect or onAuthStateChanged in the right places.

Comment: Firebase can be tricky to pick up, I still learn more each day. Keep persevering, your fruits will come to fruition eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

This was 100% user error on my part, but I wanted to share since some of my issues seem pretty common. In addition to AspiringApollo's advice above, I had my function completely out of order (as I mentioned, hook newbie). The above plus structuring my function like this fixed it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = 
    fire.auth()
    .onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        let uid = user.uid
        console.log(user.email + ' is logged in!');
        setLoggedIn(true)
        // all the things you want to do while the user is logged in goes here
      } else {
        setLoggedIn(false)
        console.log('user is logged out!');
      }
      return () => {
        unsubscribe();
      };
    });
  }, []);
```

Still open to suggestions and more sets of eyes because I know this is a little messy!